# Custom date filter angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unix-timestamp, angularjs-filter

I'm new to angularJS so a little of help would be really apreciated :)

I have this Json data

```
"map": {
    "someData": "someContent",
    "date": "1456733442000"
},
"map": {
    "someData": "someContent",
    "date": "1456733442000"
},
..... and so on
```

With this, my client needs some filters to display all the files for example in December 2015 (without bothering about the day and the hour)

This is my custom filter so far :

```js
angular.module('files').filter('FilterByDate', function() {

return function(items, year, month, day) {

    var filtered = [];

    if (year=== undefined || month == undefined || day == undefined) {

        return items

    } else if  (year === "all" && month == "all" && day == "all"){

        return items

    } else

        {

            month = month -1;

            var subDate = new Date(year,month,day);

            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

                var fileDate = new Date(items[i].map.date);

                fileDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);

                if (fileDate.getTime() == subDate.getTime()) {

                   filtered.push(items[i]);

                }

            }

        }
        return filtered;

      };

    });
```

As you can see this filter actually works, but it's not really doing what I would like to. For example the possibility to only filter from the year, leaving the rest of thes filters in "all"

Please let me know if you need more details I'll glad to answer you.

**UPDATE :**

This is much better and simplier to use thanks Alon Eitan !

```
    angular.module('Interfaces').filter('FilterByDate', function() {

  return function(items, annee, mois, jour) {

    var filtered = [];

    if (year === undefined || month == undefined || day == undefined) {

      return items

    } else if  (year === "all" && month == "all" && day == "all"){

        return items

    } else

            {

            var controlJour;

            //If the day is set as "all" we add 01 so moment() can handle it

            if (day == "all") {

                day = "01";

                controlJour = false;

            } else {

                controlJour = true;

            }

            month = month -1;

            var subDate = new Date(annee,mois,jour);

            //we loop trought the data

            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

                var fileDate = new Date(items[i].map.date);

                //erase the hours seconds a milli for prevent conflicts

                fileDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);

                //if the date of the file cames after the chosen date AND it's from the same year AND the same month we continue

                if (moment(fileDate).isSameOrAfter(subDate) && moment(fileDate).isSame(subDate, 'year') && moment(fileDate).isSame(subDate, 'month')) {   

                    if (controlJour == false) {

                        filtered.push(items[i]);

                    } else if (moment(fileDate).isSame(subDate, 'day')) {

                        filtered.push(items[i]);

                    }

              }

            }
        }

    return filtered;

  };

});
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) for this, it's allow you to query a given date against another date, take a look at this link http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

Comment: This looks amasing ! I'll try to use it and I let you know how it went, thanks !

Comment: It works like a charm, really easy to understand and use, thank you very much !!